# Sort objects in ArrayList based on priority given to the properties of object

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I need to sort an arraylist of students named studentsList who posses different scores like behavior, reading, math.

```
    public class Student{
            private String name;
            int behaviorScore;
            int readingScore;
            int mathScore;
    }
```

I have created a default constructor, getters and setters for every property.

There is an arraylist of strings which will store string named priorityList which will store the order based on which the studentsList need to be sorted. The elements for the priorityList will be added dynamically.

For example, let priorityList look like the below one
{"behavior","reading","math"}

Now, I need to sort the students in the studentsList based on the order in the priorityList.

Anyone, please help with this sorting problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Please visit the [help] to learn what is expected before you post a question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) with custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Comment: I am trying the same. But, I need to write logic for each every combination of the priorityList using if else or switch conditions which is making the logic more messy. So I am trying if I can find any logic without using more conditions.

Comment: In your case you can pass some shared object into constructor of comparator which can store intermediate calculation results (incl. copy of source array)

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

Comment: Thank you tillias. I got the list sorted

Comment: @VamshiKrishna Some one asked me same question in interview.. And this is the reference I got on google. I would appreciate if you will share some line of code to understand how did you achieve this thing.